# VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" not working in Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I have the following code to create a list of checkbox which contains 29 element:

```
            <ScrollView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
    <StackLayout>
        <syncfusionList:SfListView IsScrollBarVisible="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Check}" x:Name="fleet_checkList" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <syncfusionList:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <button:SfCheckBox Text="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" CheckedColor="LightCoral"  FontSize="20" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </syncfusionList:SfListView.ItemTemplate>                   
        </syncfusionList:SfListView>        
    </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Even though I have set the scrollBarVisibility to always, but it still didn't work, it seems like having two scrollbars duplicate each other now, but both of them only showing up when I start to scroll and disappear again after I leave my finger from the screen. Please help, thank you.

Comment: is Visible work? I use this in wpf..

Comment: Hi , which version of Xamarin Forms and Visual Studio you use ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, my Xamarin.Forms version: 3.6.0.344457 and my Visual Studio version: 8.3.2 (build 32)

Comment: @JCYOUNG Okey , the version of XF is not the latest , you can first upgrade Xamarin.Forms version to the latest version 4.2 to have  a try .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I have upgrade the version of Xamarin.Forms, but I cannot view it anymore, it become blank, is the list view cannot be placed inside a scroll view?

Comment: @JCYOUNG No it can be , maybe something not set correctly . However , I have 
also tested the latest version of XF . It occurs the same result with your problem. I think it maybe an issue in Forms . Then submit it in Github [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8015) . Later you can follow it up here . And about listview not working in Xamarin Forms can not be solved , you can ceate a new question in SO .Then people will know the new question to help you solve it.